# Truffle Migrate SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

I am trying to follow the truffle pet shop tutorial and I am doing my first truffle migration.

After this command:

```
truffle migrate
```

I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>       at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
>       at Object.createScript (vm.js:246:10)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-require/require.js:96:1
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)

I tried installing the latest truffle, deleting the contract/build folder and compile again, changing the pragma solidity ^0.4.17; to pragma solidity ^0.4.24; to make Adoption.sol pragma version to be consistent with the one on Migrations.sol

Anyone solved this error before?

Comment: What is the content of your migrations scripts? Can you add the whole output of the `truffle migrate` command?

Comment: (Solved) It was like this: 

2_deploy_contracts.js.  

var Adoption = artifacts.require("Adoption");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Adoption);
};

// It worked when I deleted the name of the file - on the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem that when I named the migrations file as 2_deploy_contracts.js, the name was placed on the file itself. Once I deleted this line, it worked

Comment: I am having the same problem. What do you mean by "the name was placed on the file itself"? do you mean it was within the code in the file or the title of the file?

Comment: it was in the code in the file

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here when I was following the tutorial of Dapp University. Deleted the 2_deploy_contracts.js file and it works.

Comment: It is more common to make your modifications in `2_deploy_contracts.js` and leave the script `1_initial_migration.js` alone. But it should work if you modify only one and delete the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the **2_deploy_contracts.js** file and edit the **1_initial_migration.js**.

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Your_contract_name");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have resolved it by changing the encoding from **UTF-16LE** to **UTF-8**

***Error:***

[image]

After adding the following solution, it starts working fine for me

[image]

If you are using VSCode then you can change Encoding by using the following:

**1)** Change encoding, choose the option "Reopen with Encoding"

**2)** And if you see weird character then type **CTRL+Z** and save the file

**3)** Run the command and you are done.

[image]